# What is a clean alternative to casting in order to call a hidden class method in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, casting, type-safety

I have two projects with some shared structure, but different project specific requirements. To cope with that, I created two base classes:

```py
class AbstractBaseClassA:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # do something
        pass


class AbstractBaseClassB:
    def __init__(self, a: AbstractBaseClassA) -> None:
        self.a = a
        # do something
```

I have a couple of abstract methods in there, do some work that is shared between the projects, but now want to go into project specifics. I thus create two further classes:

```py
class ProjectSpecificClassA(AbstractBaseClassA):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        # do something

    def someOtherMethod(self) -> None:
        # do something
        pass


class ProjectSpecificClassB(AbstractBaseClassB):
    def __init__(self, a: ProjectSpecificClassA) -> None:
        super().__init__(a)
        # do something
        self.a.someOtherMethod()  # <-- unresolved attribute reference
```

Now, in the last line of the `ProjectSpecificClassB`, I would like to call a project specific function of `ProjectSpecificClassA`, but due to the inheritance of `AbstractBaseClassB`, this method is not known. In a language like Java, this is the point where I would cast `self.a` to `ProjectSpecificClassA`, but since python does not support casting, I am looking for an alternative. I am aware, that technically, above solution works, but I'm wondering whether there is a *cleaner* solution that is also acknowledged by linters / precompilers?

Comment: What component is raising the error? Is it a runtime exception? An then what is the exact error message? Or is it a linter message and then what application is raising the error and again what is the exact message?

Comment: `ProjectSpecificClassB` and its ancestor classes  have nothing to do with method lookup for the value assigned to `self.a`, which is an instance of `ProjectSpecificClassA`. Please provide a [mcve] along with a stack trace that demonstrates the actual problem.

Comment: This is, what I was hinting at in the last sentence: The 'error' (a warning rather) is produced by an inspection of my IDE (IntelliJ idea with python plugin). Again, I am aware, that the provided code works, but it seemed like there might be a cleaner solution. | 

@SergeBallesta I know that python being dynamic is one of the things that make it flexible and great, but thought there might be a way to write code that does the same, but in a less dynamic way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is dynamic. That means that the `someOtherMethod` will be searched at run time, and will be found since `a` is actually a `ProjectSpecificClassA` object.

Casting is required in Java, like it would be in C++, because the method is searched at compile time, hence the compiler has to know where to find it.

Python is even more tolerant than that. Provided you use not special processing like `__slots__` to prevent dynamic attribute creation, you can add a method to a specific object and use it. You could use your classes that way:

```
a = ProjectSpecificClassA()
b = ProjectSpecificClassB(a)
b.a.special = lambda x: 2 * x
ProjectSpecificClassB.special = lambda self: self.a.special(3)

assert (b.special() == 6)
```